# Alamofire Error Token (Post) with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, post, token, alamofire

My mates and I are working on a iOS Project, and we get stacked in this issue.

We are trying to make a `POST request` to our API, but all we are getting is a success code but with a reponse of type:

> SUCCESS: { detail = "Authentication credentials were not provided."; }

**This is our code:**

```html
@IBAction func accept(_ sender: Any) {
    var comm,cat,dist : String!
    comm = observationstwee.text!
    print(comm)
    let catd = 7
    cat = String(catd)
    print(cat)
    dist = distancetwee.text!
    print(dist)
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "comment":comm,
        "category":cat,
        "distance":dist,
        "timestamp":time
    ]
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Token \(token!)"]
    print(headers.debugDescription)
    Alamofire.request("https://llegoelbigotes.ubiqme.es/api/new-travel",parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON {response in switch(response.result) {

    case .success(_):
        print(response)
        print("Correct Travel")
        //changeViewController(storyboard_name: "Main", viewcontroller_name: "tabBarController", context: self)
        break

    case .failure(_):
        print("FAILURE")
        }
    }
}
```

**As well as with this call:**

```html
Alamofire.request("https://llegoelbigotes.ubiqme.es/api/new-travel",method:.post,parameters: parameters,headers:headers, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseJSON
```

We get this:

> "Extra argument 'method' in call"

Thank you so much for your help, we are working with Alamofire 4.5 and iOS 11.2

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occurs when one of the parameters it’s not correct, in your example this is probably the “headers” parameter, try:

```
let headers = ["Authorization": "Token \(token!)"]
```

And check the [Alamofire migration guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md), you could use the RequestAdapter protocol.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using post method so you need to provide the method type to the request argument code should be like that

```
request("https://llegoelbigotes.ubiqme.es/api/new-travel", method: 
.post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: 
headers).responseJSON(completionHandler:{ responseObject in
         })
```